# how to make it so i only have 2 inputs but 4 values?

Tags: c++

like there are only 2 inputs, but if there are multiple inputs in one integer. I want it so i can have multiple at a time. i need help, i just started coding and im stuck on this problem. it might seem easy to some of you, but i resorted to the internet for help;-;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    float A, B, a, b, c, d;
    cout << "Pick an two integers: \n";
    cin >> a, b;
    cin >> c, d; 
    
    A = a + b;
    B = c + d;

    cout << "Sum of factors A: " << A << endl;
    cout << "Sum of factors B: " << B << endl;

   
    if (A < B){
        cout << "Sum of factors for interger A < Integer B" << endl;
        }
        else if(A > B){
        cout << "Sum of factors for interger B < Integer A" << endl;
        }
    
    return 0;
}
```

2 inputs, 4 integers
like on input 1 i get 2 and 3
input 2 i get 3

and it acknowledges these values and procedes with the code

Comment: You mention `integer`s, but your code uses `float`s only. In any case it is not clear what you are asking. _"multiple inputs in one integer"_ - One `integer` or `float` can hold one numeric value. Maybe you need an array/tuple ?

Comment: `there are multiple inputs in one integer` that doesn't make any sense. I have no idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I highly caution when you guess and use a comma in `c++`. Many of the cases putting a coma will compile but not do what you guessed it would do having not read the documentation for the comma operator: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to use `cin` is like

```
cin >> a >> b;
cin >> c >> d;
```

instead of

```
cin >> a, b;
cin >> c, d;
```

What your original code does is actually the same as

```
cin >> a;
b;
cin >> c;
d;
```

which just reads 2 inputs, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle each input as a string and parse out individual numbers from the string. After that, you could convert them to integers.

**OR**

You could simply have the number of inputs match the number of integers you need.

### The Easy Way

Your current code only reads in data to two of your variables, `a` and `c`.

```
    cin >> a, b;
    cin >> c, d;
```

You could use this alternate code instead to fix the problem.

```
    cout << "Enter first integer: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter second integer: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << "Enter third integer: ";
    cin >> c;

    cout << "Enter last integer: ";
    cin >> d;
```

### The Roundabout Way

If you truly need to get input twice and only twice, you can parse the two inputs as text and then split them by something like a comma, and then convert the substrings into integers. However, I don't see why you would need to do it that way.

If this is the route you want to take, you can use these resources to learn about tokenizing to split a string and how to convert strings in c++.

- [Split a string](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-split-a-string-in-cc-python-and-java/)
- [Convert a string to an integer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-string-to-int-in-cpp/)